# Glass to pass intent through glass app

Tags: google-glass

I have a google glass device and I know I can hack it to run native android apps.  I was hoping there was a way to just pass "INTENT"s from glass to the glass app on a paired phone and have that glass app pass along those intents to another app on the phone.  In this way we can just have glass pass intents from card/timeline responses/actions and glass app be a passthrough.

Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this is supported right now.  Of course it is possible.  You can make a feature request here:   https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement

Good idea!